How to take a screenshot of a a-scene of AFRAME on button click and download it
I am using ascene and i want to take a screenshot on button click with 3d element
I have added an Iframe in html file and want to take a screenshot of the iframe with 3d element place on a-scene how to do that


<iframe id="aframeFrame" src="tabular_navbar.html" width="200" height="400" onload="handleIframeLoad()">
         <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
<button id="capture-screenshot">Capture Screenshot</button>



tabular_navbar.html
<a-scene mindar-face embedded vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false">
      <a-camera active="false" position="0 0 0"></a-camera>
      <a-entity mindar-face-target="anchorIndex: 1">
        <a-sphere color="green" radius="0.1"></a-sphere>
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>

